# How to detect empty lines while reading from ifstream in C++

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

When I read from a file, I want to detecte the empty line. I tried `line.empty()` and `line.size()==0`, and `line==""`, however none of that worked for me.

Any advice?

```
void readFile(const string & fn){
    ifstream fichier;
    string line;
    try{
        fichier.open(fn.c_str(),ifstream::in);
        while(getline(fichier,line))
        {
            if(line.empty())// i tried also line=="" and line.size()==0
            {
                cout<<"empty line!!"<<endl;
            }
            else{
                cout<<"Line:"<<line<<endl;
            }
        }
        fichier.close();

    }catch(const string & msg){
        if(fichier.is_open()) fichier.close();
        cout<<"Error !!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the lines actually *are* empty? There's no spaces in them? And you *do* have "empty" lines in the input file?

Comment: What happens if you clear out the line at the end of each iteration like `line.clear()`?

Comment: Could you add an example of some of your text lines possibly with a few that should be empty?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: yes  you're right, there is some space in my file and i dont detecte them, because i have a big file, now when i delete the spaces in line, it's work, thank you !!

Comment: @NathanOliver yes I do it and it work thank you !!

Comment: Side notes: you don't need to explicitly close `fichier`, the destructor will take care of that. There is also nothing in your code that throws a `string`. And you don't need to pass `in` to an in-stream.

Comment: Okey @molbdnilo , thank you :), I am beginner in C++ :)

Comment: You do not need to explicitly close file, it will be closed by destructor if necessary

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
string buffer;
getline(fichier, buffer, '\n);
if(isEmpty(buffer)){
  //do whatever
}
```

If you're sure your line is fully empty (i.e no spaces, tabs or non textual characters, your isEmpty function can be something like 
`return buffer=="";`

If it's more complicated, and your newline can contain chars like \t for instance, you can do something like this:

```
bool isEmpty(string buffer){
  for (int i = 0; i<buffer.length(); i++{
    if (buffer[i] != '\t') //add chars you want to exempt here
      return false;
  }
return true;
}
```